# Права пользователей на уровне приложения

Tags: delphi, права

В существующем приложении возникла необходимость реализовать разграничение прав пользователей. Программа работает с MS SQL сервером, который расположен на хостинге и там нет возможности создавать своих пользователей. Сейчас все ходят под одним логином.

Нужно для отдельных пользователей скрывать те или иные контролы, делать их read-only и т.д.

Одно из решений - это сделать таблицы пользователей, групп пользователей и связку контрола с группой, например и при создании формы делать все проверки, но пока в голове не складывается четкая картинка того, как это все должно работать.

Посмотрел старую версию TMS Security, но мне не нравится, что там все реализовано через прямое обращение к таблицам.

Если есть у кого-то наработки по этой теме, то буду очень признателен. Мне нужны не столько исходники, сколько понимание того как это можно реализовать.

Comment: вы бы объемы приложения указали бы еще. 1 форма, 5 форм, или 500 форм?

Comment: Около 30 форм, но это особой роли не играет.

Comment: У меня тоже приложение ходит через одного пользователя, в БД хранятся пользователи/группы. В приложении захардкожены группы и доступ, но их тоже можно было вынести в БД, просто надобности не было. Поскольку есть общие таблицы - написал ORM обертки для того чтобы на формах работать с объектами, а не присать SQL запросы.

Comment: @androschuk А можно поподробнее про ORM обертки? Как происходит разграничение прав на те или иные контролы?

Comment: Разграничения по контролам у меня нет, только на уровне форм(доступна или нет).  [ORM (объектно-реляционное отображение)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) служит только для управления данными. К примеру у вас есть табличка в БД. Вы описываете специальный класс который взаимодействует с БД (добавление, удаление, редактирование), а дальше не пишите запросы для манипуляции данными, а работаете с объектами (экземпдярами вышесозданного класса).

Comment: @androschuk Спасибо за разъяснения, но это не совсем то, что нужно. Но, возможно, такой подход может где-нибудь и пригодится.

Comment: @androschuk Какую ORM используете, если не секрет?

Comment: @zed а есть выбор кроме EntityDAC?

Comment: @Zam выбор всегда есть. Я, к примеру, использовал опенсорсный mORMot.

Comment: @zed на тот момент (2011 г.) был придуман свой костыль - подобие ORM. Хотя и костыль, но был выпилено SQL код с ~ 300 форм.

Comment: @androschuk с использованием RTTI ?

Comment: @Zam Да, с помощью RTTI и аттрибутов. По крайнер мере мапинг полей.

Comment: А в чем преимущество использования ORM? Я пока увидел только то, что не нужно писать SQL запросы в самом коде программы, но у меня и так везде используются хранимые процедуры. Может быть есть другие плюшки? И это скорее не тема для этого вопроса:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встречал подобное решение.

Таблица пользователей: USER_NAME, ID_GROUP, LOGIN, PASSWORD (зашифрованный)

Таблица контролов: ID_CONTROL, NAME, ID_PARENT. NAME соответствует имени контрола на форме или имени формы. ID_PARENT нужен чтобы при запуске формы вычитать только ее контролы.

Таблица групп: ID_GROUP, GROUP_NAME

И таблица разрешений: ID_GROUP, ID_CONTROL - если запись есть, то контрол можно использовать.